# AutoMapper IMappingEngine ConfigurationStore Initialize Not Happening

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, automapper, automapper-3

AutoMapper Version Used :   3.3.10

```
[TestClass]
public class AppControllerTests
{
    private IMappingEngine _mappingEngine = null;
    private ConfigurationStore _configurationStore = null;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
      _configurationStore = new ConfigurationStore(new TypeMapFactory(), MapperRegistry.Mappers);
        _configurationStore.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfile.AppProfile());
        _mappingEngine = new MappingEngine(_configurationStore);
     }

     [TestMethod]
    public void GetAppByAccountID()
    {
        // Error line 
        var mappingResult = _mappingEngine.Map<Category>(categoryList).AsQueryable();
    }
}

public class AppProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
      AutoMapperMappingConfigurations();
    }
    public void AutoMapperMappingConfigurations()
    {
         Mapper.CreateMap<DomainModels.Category, Category>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Exception:

> An exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException'
>   occurred in AutoMapper.dll but was not handled in user code.

Suspect the

```
_configurationStore.AddProfile(new OOS.PresentationModelService.AutoMapperProfile.AppProfile());
```

is not able to create an istance of AppProfile if i write the manual mapping it's working as expected.

```
_configurationStore.CreateMap<Category, Category>().ReverseMap();
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Question is :_configurationStore.AddProfile(new OOS.PresentationModelService.AutoMapperProfile.AppProfile()); is not working.